# Issue rendering .NET form in Windows 7 vs XP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7

I'm working an a form with a progressbar, which is meant to have certain colors (foreground and background). On my XP machine, the colors are correct. On my Windows 7 machine, the form looks all sexified (just like all the other windows 7 windows) and the color is not what I had set in the designer.

Is there some sort of style option that is overriding my form drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove calls to `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`